# SQL Query, need help understanding it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to programming, I can program in C++, PHP, Java but I have not come across SQL Queries as of yet. I am currently studying a degree in computing.

I am self employed and had a program written for the company. As of lately the programmer can no longer do look after my program, so as I am studying programming and have a fair idea I thought I would take over the project myself.

The program is written in C# and it uses SQL to fetch data. As I said I have not come across SQL yet in study so I am a complete novice to it.

I have tried to learn SQL queries but I am having trouble understanding it. Could someone please explain what each part of the query does so I can get my head around it and hopefully understand it.

```
SELECT top 3 tracks.trackid AS id,
             TrackTitle,
             ArtistName,
             row_number() over (
                                ORDER BY Tracks.TrackPlayed DESC) AS rank,
             categorytitle,
             categorytitle AS title,
             CategoryImagePath
FROM Tracks
JOIN artists ON tracks.artistid = artists.artistid
JOIN x_categories_tracks ON x_categories_tracks.trackid = tracks.trackid
JOIN Categories ON categories.categoryid = x_categories_tracks.categoryid
WHERE trackactive = 'true'
  AND categories.categoryid = @optsId 
ORDER BY trackplayed DESC
```

If any other information is needed, pleas let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried taking that query and running it directly against the database? Also, this is just sql server right and not mysql? no value in having both tags

Comment: Certainly not MySQL - there is no row_number() windowing function...

Comment: it will simply return the top 3 tracks based on a category and the amount it is played by the look of things

Comment: Right. Was about to say, `row_number()` looks like a MS SQL Server DB

Comment: @PinnyM I was pretty sure that was just sql server but not familiar with mysql

Comment: Aside for what @Tanner said, there's also a rank by trackplayed (which is used as the sort order) and a filter on trackactive being equal to true and a specific categoryid.

Comment: Also note that this query is not being parameterized and is subject to SQL injection as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What the query does:

It returns Song/Track info for the TOP 3 Most played Tracks, that are in `Active` state, for the a given Sing/Track `Category` (passed in as parameter in the `opts.id` property.

#### Purpose each part of the query serves.

Take the first 3 Rows from the Resultset

`Select top 3`

Pick the fields from the resultset that you want for further processing
`tracks.trackid as id, TrackTitle,ArtistName,...`

Group the records that qualify in the select criteria by the `TrackPlayed` value in `desc` descending order, so the most played ones are first in the resulset.
`row_number() over (order by Tracks.TrackPlayed desc) as rank`, "

Pick some more fields from the resultset that you want for further processing
`+"categorytitle,categorytitle as title, CategoryImagePath from Tracks "`

SQL Join conditions to link various tables that are related.
`+ "join artists on tracks.artistid = artists.artistid " +`
   `"join x_categories_tracks on x_categories_tracks.trackid = tracks.trackid " +`
    `"join Categories on categories.categoryid =  x_categories_tracks.categoryid " +`

`WHERE` clause for filtering records. Here we select only the tracks that are active, and that belong to the Category stored in `opts.id` (passed in as parameter?)
`"where trackactive = 'true' and categories.categoryid = " + opts.id + "`

finally, sort the TOP 3 records returned in descending order of the times they were played (i.e. most played coming up 1st).
`order by trackplayed desc";`

Comment: Thanks a lot CodeProDevkota

Comment: @Shiva that was a good answer to the question.  Why did you also vote the question to be put on hold for being too broad though?

Comment: At first glance I thought it was too broad, hence the vote. Then I put myself in OP's shoes, and realized I've been in this situation many times (inheriting someone else's code) myself, and though it was right to help OP out. Hence the detailed answer. As you know, Flags can't be retracted in SO. Hence it stayed there...

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding the SQL code that you provided above, you should try to understand what each SQL command do.some of the topics that you need to understand before reading this SQL statement are:

```
SELECT, TOP, Alias Table, Ranking Functions, ORDER BY, JOINS, WHERE.
```

If you learn there commands, I'm sure you will understand the code very easily.